# How can I display a JBoss property in JSTL (without using Java)?

Tags: spring, jsp, jboss, jstl, jboss7.x

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3 and Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I have this property defined in my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file

```
<system-properties>
    <property name=“myProperty” value=“myValue”/>
    …
```

In my JSP, through JSTL, is it possible to access this value without any additional code in a Java servlet?  If I need to put something in a Spring XML application context file to accommodate this, that’s fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are real system properties, just add a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your application, and in its `contextInitialized()` method, store the system properties in the servlet context:

```
servletContext.setAttribute("systemProperties", System.getProperties());
```

Then, in any JSP:

```
<c:out value="${systemProperties.myProperty}"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer although in my quesiton I did specify "without using Java".

Comment: Creating Java applications without using Java won't get you very far. And, since you're nitpicking, you didn't say that. You said "without any additional code in a Java servlet".